# Eliminating certain data from a data set with regular expression

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataset of certain words (diminutives like Bäumchen, Tischchen) that still contains some "error" words. What I want to do now is to kick those out with a regular expression, so that my final output in the end is only diminutive words. I know I have to put in the words like this

('kirche|drachen|lachen.....')

because the | acts as "or".

But which prompt do I need so my output is without those excluded ones? I can't simply use

regexr('kirche|drachen|lachen.....')

since that didn't yield the result I wanted. I also tried working with the `stringr` package from `tidyverse` but gave up quickly since I need a different command here. But if anyone has an idea for `stringr` I am welcoming that too.
If you need more info on the data set let me know.

So far I tried

regexr('kirche|drachen|lachen.....')

Answer (score -1):

According to https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html this is the method from stringr to do this:

```
str_replace_all(string, pattern, replacement)
```

I assume you should call like this

```
str_replace_all(yourstring, "kirche|drachen|lachen.....", "")
```

this should replace the words with nothing